# sql syntax group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Struggling with this as i'm not good with sql and designer wont work with the OVER use. Basically this is getting a list of topics if the user is following an associated tag.

I need to group by `T.TopicId` to stop duplicates. If a user is selecting more than one tag associated with a topic it will list the topic twice (once for each tag)

When I add a group by in sql I get multiple errors and i've tried rearranging things and cant get it to work, As said i'm useless with sql statements

```
@id int = null
AS
SELECT
*
FROM
(SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER 
            (ORDER BY TopicOrder desc
             ,
             (CASE 
                WHEN M.MessageCreationDate > T.TopicCreationDate THEN M.MessageCreationDate
                ELSE T.TopicCreationDate
            END) desc)
        AS RowNumber
    ,T.TopicId, T.TopicTitle, T.TopicShortName, T.TopicDescription, T.TopicCreationDate, T.TopicViews, T.TopicReplies, T.UserId, T.TopicTags, T.TopicIsClose, 
                     T.TopicOrder, T.LastMessageId, T.UserName, M.MessageCreationDate, M.UserId     AS MessageUserId, MU.UserName AS MessageUserName, U.UserGroupId, 
                     U.UserPhoto, T.UserFullName
FROM            Tags INNER JOIN
                     TopicsComplete AS T ON T.TopicId = Tags.TopicId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Messages AS M ON M.TopicId = T.TopicId AND M.MessageId = T.LastMessageId AND     M.Active = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Users AS MU ON MU.UserId = M.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Users AS U ON U.UserId = T.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     tagfollows AS TF ON @id = TF.userid
WHERE        (Tags.Tag = TF.tag)
 )T
```

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Looks way too complicated for what you say you want.  By the way, is this sql server?

Comment: yeah it is, this code works fine. i just wanted to put the group by under the where but then it complains that all the T.'s arnt in an aggregate function or group by

Comment: You could just convert the join to `tagfollows` into an `EXISTS` subquery.

Comment: hi ypercube, any chance u can show how this would look like, ive been trying to create an extra subquery with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to convert the join to `tagfollows` into an `EXISTS` subquery (and remove the redundant nesting):

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER ( ORDER BY TopicOrder desc
                      , CASE WHEN M.MessageCreationDate > T.TopicCreationDate 
                            THEN M.MessageCreationDate
                            ELSE T.TopicCreationDate
                        END desc )
        AS RowNumber,
    T.TopicId, T.TopicTitle, T.TopicShortName, T.TopicDescription, 
    T.TopicCreationDate, T.TopicViews, T.TopicReplies, T.UserId, 
    T.TopicTags, T.TopicIsClose, T.TopicOrder, T.LastMessageId, 
    T.UserName, M.MessageCreationDate, 
    M.UserId    AS MessageUserId, 
    MU.UserName AS MessageUserName, 
    U.UserGroupId, U.UserPhoto, T.UserFullName
FROM
        TopicsComplete AS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Messages AS M        ON  M.TopicId = T.TopicId 
                             AND M.MessageId = T.LastMessageId
                             AND M.Active = 1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Users AS MU          ON  MU.UserId = M.UserId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Users AS U           ON  U.UserId = T.UserId
WHERE   EXISTS
        ( SELECT  *
          FROM    Tags
              INNER JOIN tagfollows AS TF
                  ON  Tags.Tag = TF.tag 
          WHERE   T.TopicId = Tags.TopicId 
            AND   @id = TF.userid   
        ) ;
```

Comment: hey ypercube, thanks for trying but this returns the same data. the problem is that if a use is following 2 tags the tagfollows will be for example 1 sample, 1 sample2 (the 1 being userid) . if a topic has both tags sample and sample2 associated with it it will return a result for both tags. If it was done by a group by TopicId then it would just group any duplicates. Not sure if where exists applies as both tags will exist as a seperate Tags.Tag

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to show posts with tags in the set that the user is following, but you don't want the post to show up multiple times when it has multiple matching tags. That's a perfect use for an [`EXISTS` subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx). Here's an example from that MSDN page.

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName
FROM Person.Person AS a
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * 
    FROM HumanResources.Employee AS b
    WHERE a.BusinessEntityID = b.BusinessEntityID
    AND a.LastName = 'Johnson');
```

You're really interested in the person table (like your posts table), but you want to show records that have at least one matching record in employee (like your tags table).